# Javascript library to scan QR CODE mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, qr-code

I am looking for a library to scan QR Codes for my mobile website (mobile browser). I have tried the ZXing library but I have to do much steps for validate the QR decode:

```
1) open camera
2) take photo of QR CODE
3) upload the photo
4) manage qr code information decoded
```

I am looking for a library that opens directly the camera for capturing the QR code and then scan automatically without having to take the picture like mostly apps do.

Anyone knows some library in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Scandit](https://www.scandit.com/products/web-sdk/), but that is a paid solution.